# Mount "Macrium Reflect" on a partition, boot from there?

Tags: linux, mount, grub, livecd

Can Macrium's Reflect recovery CD be mounted/used with GRUB ?

If the cd can be 'put' (loaded/mounted/...) in a partition, then the only disc needed would be the actual recovery disc, which could be on an external hard drive, or even on the same machine in another partition, thus allowing on to recover using only what's on the machine itself.

I have WXPpro and Xubuntu8.04 double mounted, really happy with them together, use each right now to fix problems with the other when they come up. Also have a partition for the Reflect CD, but I just can't get it to load from Grub, which would be great...

Thanks for any thoughts, probably someone has already done this I know !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Macrium Reflect specifically, but as it is Linux grub will be able to boot it. The commands you want to use are:

```
root (hdx,y)
linux /ISOLINUX/linux26
initrd /ISOLINUX/initrd.bin
boot
```

Where *x* is your disk number counting from 0 and *y* is the partition number counting from 0 (or 1 if you are using grub2). It is probably a good idea to check the contents of `isolinux.cnf` for any additional command line parameters, add these on to the end of the `linux...` line.

Answer (score 0):

Macrium reflect itself is only an application. It is not an OS and does not include a boot loader to enable this.

The correct way to do this would be to setup a small windows partition (WinPE or similiar) and have reflect start inside that OS.

Comment: Hmm, 
Knew it was only an application, so the winpe idea is great, but the application creates a recovery CD with very little on it but a linux kernel, so thought that that CD image is what might mount in a partition and launch with grub?

CD contents:
Folder "ISOLINUX":
   boot.cat
   initrd.bin
   isolinux.bin
   isolinux.cfg
   linux26
   menu.txt
   version

Anyone with ideas ? It would be neat to use it with few mods !
Cheers.

Comment: They use Linux because WinPE cannot be handed out freely. If you've bought a copy of Macrium Reflect, you have the capability to download the WinPE image.